# Trying to calculate a formula that gets closer to e but program just wont work

Tags: function, math

Im wrote a code that calculates this formula ((2*x+1)/(2*x-1))^x and as x increases this expression gets closer to e=2.7182818.When the difference between that expression and e gets smaller than .000001 then it will exit the loop and display what x is.The problem is is first it would calcute it wrong and then when i made some adjustments the loop started to go on forever.
Thanks for the help in advanced.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

    int x;
    float z,y;

    printf("X's value       Absolute Difference\n");
    x=1;
    y=(2*x+1)/(2*x-1);
    z=fabsf(expf(1)-pow(y,x));

    for(x=2;z>0.000001;++x){
        y=(2*x+1)/(2*x-1);
        z=fabsf(expf(1)-pow(y,x));
        printf("%d               %.7f\n",x,z);
    }
    printf("The number in which is closest to e is %d\n",x);
    printf("%.7f             %.7f\n",expf(1),pow(y,x));

     return(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `y=(2*x+1)/(2*x-1)` to `y = 1.*(2*x+1)/(2*x-1)`.

Otherwise, `y` is being rounded to one, and you're stuck in the infinite loop. To see this, simply print `y` at each iteration:

```
printf("%d               %.7f   %.7f\n",x,z, y);
                                ^^^^         ^
```

Comment: may i ask why you did this...the program worked thanks! but i want to know why you changed it to y = 1.*(2*x+1)/(2*x-1)